# bash script can't check file exists

Tags: linux, bash

Hello everybody: I have a bash script that check if a file exists and with that information create a new file. The part of the script with the problem is this..

```
#!/bin/bash 
FECHA=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
FECHAD=$(date +%d)
FECHAM=$(date +%m)
FECHAA=$(date +%Y)

DIRECTORY="/home/usuario/Build_WRF/DATA/"
FILE1=$DIRECTORY"GFS_24"
FILE2=$DIRECTORY"GFS_48"
FILE3=$DIRECTORY"GFS_72"
FILE4=$DIRECTORY"GFS_96"
FILE5=$DIRECTORY"GFS_120"
FILE6=$DIRECTORY"GFS_144"
FILE7=$DIRECTORY"GFS_168"
FILE8=$DIRECTORY"GFS_192"
FILE9=$DIRECTORY"GFS_216"
FILE10=$DIRECTORY"GFS_240"

if [ -f $FILE10 ]; then
        dias="10 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE9 ]; then
        dias="9 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE8 ]; then
        dias="8 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE7 ]; then
        dias="7 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE6 ]; then
        dias="6 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE5 ]; then
        dias="5 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE4 ]; then
    dias="4 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE3 ]; then
    dias="3 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE2 ]; then
    dias="2 days"
        echo $dias
elif [ -f $FILE1 ]; then
    dias="1 day"
        echo $dias
else
    exit
fi

FECHAF=$(date +%Y-%m-%d --date="$dias")
FECHAFD=$(date +%d --date="$dias")
FECHAFM=$(date +%m --date="$dias")
FECHAFA=$(date +%Y --date="$dias")
```

The files exists, for example today I have the file GFS_72, the script should return 3 days, but return nothing.
I'm missing something.
Cheers.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please read the section "How do I convert a bad script to a good question", further down from the top of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Good luck.

Comment: As a side note shell variables in all CAPS are reserved. Setting them can have strange and unexpected behaviours.

Comment: Try using your script with a `set -x` before the first if. This will print what bash is doing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's the all-lowercase names that are reserved for user applications. POSIX chooses to restrict itself to uppercase/digit/`_` names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your script and it worked for me.

Please check that `/home/usuario/Build_WRF/DATA/GFS_72` actually exists and the directory `/home/usuario/Build_WRF/DATA/` is readable and executable as **the user the script is executing as**.

For instance, as a debugging technique, insert at the top of the script:

```bash
ls -la /home/usuario/Build_WRF/DATA/ || {
    echo "Directory not readable as user $USER" >&2
    id
    exit 1
}
```

### Further style issues / Bash tips:

When using `[`...`]`, you should always quote the arguments to prevent split on space.

```bash
if [ -f "$FILE10" ]; then
        dias="10 days"
        echo "$dias"
elif ...
```

If you *know* this is going to be running in Bash, you should use `[[`...`]]` instead, where you don't have to use quoting (except on the RHS of `=`).

`[[`...`]]` is also marginally faster than `[`...`]` in most cases, and it has more features like glob comparisons, regex, and more.

```bash
if [[ -f $FILE10 ]]; then
        dias="10 days"
        echo "$dias"
elif ...
```

Comment: I'd also recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names instead of all-caps. There are a lot of all-caps names with special meanings, and using one of those by accident can cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps, to avoid the `if`s

```
dias="$(( $(echo $DIRECTORY/GFS_* | sed 's![^ ]*GFS_!!g; s! !\n!g' | sort -n | tail -n 1) / 24 )) days"
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you go from 10 to 1, I would do it shorter and without external calls, something like this:

```bash
DIRECTORY="./DATA"
dias=""
for (( i=10; i>=1; i-- ))
do
    [ -f "${DIRECTORY}/GFS_$((i * 24))" ] && dias="$i days" && break
done
[ -z "$dias" ] && exit
echo $dias
```

Comment: BTW, original script didn't work for me either, might be because I mistyped when creating one of those files